# Annotate (Comment) bundle with Webpack?

Tags: webpack

Is there some way to annotate a Webpack bundle with build date and time ?  It would be nice to add the module version and some 'free text notes'  too.

I've looked through the docs and haven't found any way to do that, I imagine it would be a common need to label bundles.